# Correct way (if possible) to store JSX code into a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, babeljs

I´ve written the following code using `ReactJs´s JSX` syntax:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class SidebarMenuItem extends React.Component {

render() {

    var href = (this.props.submenu ? 'javascript:' : {<Link to="mod/admin" + this.props.link />};

    return ( 

        <a href={href} onClick={this.selected}>
            <i className={'fa ' + this.props.icon} />
            <span>{this.props.title}</span>
        </a>

    )
  }
}
```

But it seend that I cannot store a direct JSX code into a variable, as I got the following error:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: D:/9. DEV/client/components/App/SidebarMenuItem.js: Unexpected token, expected , (41:52)

  40 | 
> 41 |      var href = (this.props.submenu ? 'javascript:' : {<Link to="mod/admin" + this.props.link />};
     |                                                        ^
```

What  is the correct way to store my Link component in the `href` variable ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about what you're trying to achieve? `href` attribute expects a string. Or you put `<Link>` as a replacement for `<a>`. And your code is syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you would just write plain jsx, in your case you need to remove the brackets around the jsx, and then include the brackets around the "mod/admin" + this.props.link portion just like you would when you write in the render method.

```
var href = this.props.submenu ? 'javascript:' : <Link to={"mod/admin" + this.props.link} />
```

Answer (score 7):

Use () around JSX that spans multiple lines

```
var href = this.props.submenu ? 'javascript:' : (<Link to="mod/admin" + this.props.link />);
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I actually hadn't closely seen what exactly you were trying to achieve, what exactly are you trying to assign to href? You also have an opening parenthesis after the = sign, and you never close it

Comment: Parentheses aren't required to split JSX tags across multiple lines.